# Не выводятся поля advanced custom fields на странице категорий товаров WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-плагины

Вот уже который день не могу решить одну проблему. Мне нужно вывести дополнительный заголовок на одной странице категорий товаров. Для создания нового произвольного поля использовал плагин advanced custom fields. В админке создана необходимая страница с пометкой "страница магазина". Я могу редактировать её с помощью файла woocommerce.php, также этот файл отвечает за отображение категорий. Пробовал разные способы по типу get_field, the_field, но все безуспешно. Мне кажется проблема в том, что и нужная мне страница и категории генерируются одним и тем же файлом (woocommerce.php) и вероятно из-за этого возникает ошибка. В теге div с классом "title-sup" я пытаюсь вывести кастомное поле которое сделал с помощью плагина Advanced custom fields, но ничего не выводится, тег на выходе пустой и я не могу понять почему.

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: WooCommerce
*/
?>

<?php
global $woocommerce;


$id = get_option('woocommerce_shop_page_id');
$shop = get_post($id);
$shop = get_post($id);
$sidebar = get_post_meta($id, "qode_show-sidebar", true);

if (get_query_var('paged')) {
    $paged = get_query_var('paged');
} elseif (get_query_var('page')) {
    $paged = get_query_var('page');
} else {
    $paged = 1;
}

$content_style_spacing = "";
if(get_post_meta($id, "qode_margin_after_title", true) != ""){
    if(get_post_meta($id, "qode_margin_after_title_mobile", true) == 'yes'){
        $content_style_spacing = "padding-top:".esc_attr(get_post_meta($id, "qode_margin_after_title", true))."px !important";
    }else{
        $content_style_spacing = "padding-top:".esc_attr(get_post_meta($id, "qode_margin_after_title", true))."px";
    }
}

$single_type = qode_woocommerce_single_type();
$woo_content_width = 'grid';
if($single_type == 'wide-gallery') {
    $woo_content_width = 'full';
}

?>
<?php
    get_header();
    $id = get_option('woocommerce_shop_page_id');
?>
    <?php if(get_post_meta($id, "qode_page_scroll_amount_for_sticky", true)) { ?>
        <script>
        var page_scroll_amount_for_sticky = <?php echo get_post_meta($id, "qode_page_scroll_amount_for_sticky", true); ?>;
        </script>
    <?php } ?>

    <?php get_template_part( 'title' ); ?>
    

    <?php
    $revslider = get_post_meta($id, "qode_revolution-slider", true);
    if (!empty($revslider)){ ?>
        <div class="q_slider"><div class="q_slider_inner">
        <?php echo do_shortcode($revslider); ?>
        </div></div>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    <?php if($woo_content_width == 'full' && is_singular('product')){ ?>
    <div class="full_width">
        <div class="full_width_inner clearfix" <?php qode_inline_style($content_style_spacing); ?>>
    <?php } else { ?>
            <div class="container">
                
 
                <?php if(isset($qode_options_proya['overlapping_content']) && $qode_options_proya['overlapping_content'] == 'yes') {?>
                <div class="overlapping_content"><div class="overlapping_content_inner">
                        <?php } ?>
                        <div class="container_inner default_template_holder clearfix" <?php qode_inline_style($content_style_spacing); ?>>
          
    <?php } ?>
    

     <div class="title-sup">

     <?php the_field('title_sup'); ?>
     </div>

      <?php
if ( function_exists('yoast_breadcrumb') ) {
  yoast_breadcrumb( '<p id="breadcrumbs">','</p>' );
}
?>

 
 
            <?php if(!is_singular('product')) { ?>
                <?php if($sidebar == "default" || $sidebar == "") : ?>
                    <?php woocommerce_content(); ?>
                <?php elseif($sidebar == "1" || $sidebar == "2"): ?>
                <?php global $woocommerce_loop;
                    $woocommerce_loop['columns'] = 3;
                ?>
                <?php if($sidebar == "1") : ?>
                    <div class="two_columns_66_33 woocommerce_with_sidebar grid2 clearfix">
                        <div class="column1">
                <?php elseif($sidebar == "2") : ?>
                    <div class="two_columns_75_25 woocommerce_with_sidebar grid2 clearfix">
                        <div class="column1">
                        <h1 class="product-category-title"><?php single_term_title(); ?></h1>
                <?php endif; ?>
                            <div class="column_inner">
                            
                  
                                <?php woocommerce_content(); ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="column2"><?php get_sidebar();?></div>
                    </div>
                <?php elseif($sidebar == "3" || $sidebar == "4"): ?>
                    <?php global $woocommerce_loop;
                        $woocommerce_loop['columns'] = 3;
                    ?>
                    <?php if($sidebar == "3") : ?>
                        <div class="two_columns_33_66 woocommerce_with_sidebar grid2 clearfix">
                            <div class="column1"><?php get_sidebar();?></div>
                            <div class="column2">
                    <?php elseif($sidebar == "4") : ?>
                        <div class="two_columns_25_75 woocommerce_with_sidebar grid2 clearfix">
                            <div class="column1">
          
                          
                            <?php get_sidebar();?></div>
                            <div class="column2">
                    <?php endif; ?>
                                <div class="column_inner">
                               <div class="test">  <?php single_cat_title( $prefix, $display ); ?></div>
                                    <?php woocommerce_content(); ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php } else {
                  woocommerce_content();
            } ?>
        </div>
        <?php if(isset($qode_options_proya['overlapping_content']) && $qode_options_proya['overlapping_content'] == 'yes') {?>
            <?php if($woo_content_width == 'full' && is_singular('product')){ ?>
            <?php } else { ?>
                    </div></div>
            <?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Честно говоря не до конца понял куда вы добавили поле, странице или категории. Если категории, то чтобы добавить подзаголовок для одной категории товара, Вы могли бы добавить поле непосредственно категории подробнее [здесь](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/adding-fields-taxonomy-term/) и вывести поле таким образом:

```
$queried_object = get_queried_object();

the_field( 'title_sup', $queried_object );
```

Если же Вам нужно вывести поле на какой-то категории, но для поля Вы создали страницу (потому что я сейчас это понял так, и выглядит это странновато), то Вам нужно вторым параметром добавить ID страницы. Подробнее о параметрах функции `the_field()` [здесь](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_field/)

Comment: Спасибо большое, действительно не хватало Id страницы, очень благодарен!